# SimplePrincipal cannot be cast to KeycloakPrincipal

Tags: java, session, ejb, keycloak

I'm using Keycloak to secure an enterprise application. I want to obtain the token stored in the application context and the username logged in that application.

This is my class:

```
@Stateless
public class ContextoSesionEJB {
@Resource
SessionContext sessionContext;

/**
 * Atributo utilizado para el registro de log de la aplicacion.
 */
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ContextoSesionEJB.class.getName());

/**
 * Método que valida que un usuario corresponda
 * al que esta logueado en el aplicativo
 * 
 * @param nombreUsuario
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean validarUsuario(String nombreUsuario){
    logger.info("Inicia metodo validarUsuario");

    KeycloakPrincipal keycloakPrincipal = (KeycloakPrincipal) sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal();
    if(keycloakPrincipal.getName().equals(nombreUsuario)){
        return true;
    }else{
        logger.info("El usuario no corresponde al usuario logueado");
        return false;
    }       
}

/**
 * Método encargado de obtener el token de 
 * keycloak
 * 
 * @param 
 * @return Token
 * */
public AccessToken getToken(){      
    logger.info("Inicia metodo obtenerToken");          
    //Se accede al contexto del keycloak

    KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext> keycloakPrincipal = (KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext>)sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal();
     IDToken idToken = keycloakPrincipal.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getIdToken();
    //Se obtiene y se devuelve el token
    return keycloakPrincipal.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken();
}



}
```

I have a `SessionContext` where I capture the info in the application, I have looked for a examples and I have found a lot but when I call for example the method "validarUsuario" and I make a new Instance from `KeycloakPrincipal` I receive an exception

> SimplePrincipal cannot be cast to KeycloakPrincipal

I don't know how I can do a cast to KeycloakPrincipal to the method SimplePrincipal in the SessionContext